# iPhone : how to prevent dismiss keyboard when other view presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I am having on issue with my iPhone App.

There is a 2 `UIViewController`.

First `UIViewController` with `UITextField` and keyboard up. Once I will open other `UIViewController` with presentViewController my keyboard automatically down.

So is there any way to I can forcefully open keyboard? I do not want to keyboard dismiss.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found the solution. I've got same issue  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559162/how-to-keep-a-textfield-editing-with-keyboard-view-behind-the-alert-when-alert

Answer (score 0):

You can open it in the new view controller at the earliest possible point like this (In the second view controller):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [_textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

You will see the keyboard return and then re-appear immediately..

If you want to get around that too the only way I can think of is to disable animations in presentViewController (In the first view controller):

```
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for your opinion but i need to open keyboard forcefully with animation of UIViewController Present.

Comment: [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:NO completion:nil]; still dismisses the keyboard for me