# iOS 8 Swift : How to keep the keyboard displayed when the UIAlercontroller is presented modally?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

The context is pretty simple, there is a UIViewcontroller with a textfield to enter a phone number. The textfield is in editing mode with keyboard.

When the number is entered, the user can tap a button which displays an alert controller. As the alert is presented modally it covers the UIViewcontroller and  removes keyboard, the editing is no more enabled.

Thus my question, what should be done to keep the keyboard displayed behind the alert?

Comment: I think this might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006017/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-the-keyboard-from-dismissing

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the solutions mentioned in this interesting post did not work in my case.

Comment: This issue has been raised before but not answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035395/iphone-how-to-prevent-dismiss-keyboard-when-other-view-presentviewcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution worked

```
let rootViewController: UIViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[1].rootViewController!!
rootViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't. Better try making custom alert which can allow pass-through gestures.

Comment: Thanks Amresh for your answer. I might not have been precise enough. I just want the keyboard to be displayed and cursor in textfield (editing mode) behind alert. I'm not looking for any user interaction regarding textfield.

Comment: I have never tried this before, but may be returning NO from canResignFirstResponder for the current text field can do the trick